# Is there a way to execute a Checkmarx scan without the UI?

Tags: checkmarx

I would like to know if there's a way to run a Checkmarx scan without having to enter to the User Interface.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CxSAST scans can be run from the CxConsole Command Line Interface (CLI) command.

Taken from here: [Checkmarx CLI](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=3637257#content/view/3637257)

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

- CLI: https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KC/CxConsole:+CxSAST+CLI
- IDE plugins: https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KC/IDE+Plugins
- build management systems plugins: https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KC/Integrating+CxSAST+with+Third+Party+Systems